ActiveCollab how to download task's attachment?
It's my first time working with ActiveCollab API.
I'm trying to get attachments of tasks.
After getting task data 'v1/projects/'.$projectId.'/tasks/'.$taskId there is download_url element of an array of each attachment. But the url is like https://warehouse.activecollab.com/api/v1/files/2024-08%2xxxxxx.jpeg/xxxxxxxxx/download?force=1&intent=--DOWNLOAD-TOKEN--
It seems like I need a download token.
What is DOWNLOAD-TOKEN? How to get it?



https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html

@AlexHowansky thanks but it didn't help

Did you read any of it? According to https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/tasks/attachments.html you can use a URL ending  /attachments/1/download once you know the ID of the attachment - which you can get from your first request

@ADyson You were right. I didn't see attachments URLs in documentation page. I have tried to send request to v1/attachments/11860/download and I got this
Array (     [type] => RuntimeException     [message] => File not found     [code] => 0 )

Meanwhile if I send request to attachments/11860 then I get the correct data
[single] => Array         (             [id] => 11860             [class] => WarehouseAttachment             [url_path] => /attachments/11860             [name] => vw.jpg             [parent_type] => Task             [parent_id] => 17761             [mime_type] => image/jpeg             [size] => 262082             [md5] => 2907f7fc1d9b3b1dfc81db478535e535
But I still can't download it attachments/11860/download. The error says that file not found

The full url for download request is https://app.activecollab.com/'.self::$accountId.'/api/v1/attachments/'.$fileId.'/download

You should GET the token from the /api/v1/issue-file-access-token
You'll get the download token in the response. Also be aware of the TTL, since  the token will expire.

Awesome. Thanks a lot. It works.
So, no need to try download attachment by file id. All I have to do is to GET an attachment, then get the download_url of the attachment array and replace &intent=--DOWNLOAD-TOKEN-- with &intent= the token I GOT issue-file-access-token. Please update your documentation page for other people.
